# I have downloaded one project. Now i have yo import that project into my existing project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded one project and want to import that project into my existing project! I want to open that project's activity with a button on my existing project's on xml file!

I have already a main activity and that other project is also having a main activity so what to do to make that project in my existing project and open with a button! Please help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To my knowledge, you cant call the whole page unless there is a call back method and functions to define designs in the other project. But you can call its method and retrieve data. To add another project to yours, simply import it as IMPORT MODULE from File menu. FILE > New > IMPORT module > select the location of other project > give module name > Done